# Replace 2 AA batteries with 5Vdc phone charger

Tags: power-supply, led, batteries

Is there a safe and easy way to replace 2 AA batteries that power 10 LEDs in parallel with an old 5Vdc 900mA phone charger?  I think the LEDs are standard 20mA ones.

Comment: You'll likely need some external components; a set of LEDs designed for 1.2V or 2.5V (batteries is parallel or series) would probably be damaged by 5V phone charger.  Can you provide more information about what you have and are trying to achieve?

Comment: There may be, but the only way to not guess is for you to post a schematic - or describe verbally - the LEDs' circuit arrangement.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Using only a resistor did work for me with excellent results.

Answer (score 3):

Yup. Put a resistor in series with the LEDs to limit the current a bit. Start with 22 ohms. If the total LED draw is 100 mA, the resistor will drop 2.2 volts, giving about 2.8 volts to the LEDs. Use a 1/4 watt resistor or better. (0.1 x 0.1 x 22 = .22 watts, and this will make the resistor too hot to touch.) You can then experiment with lower resistor values, but don't get carried away. Depending on how the LEDs are connected, you might run into what's called "firecracker mode" failure. That is, with too much current one of the diodes fails. This increases the voltage across the others, causing the next-weakest to fail, and so on in a frenzied accelerando of failure. Just a caution.

Answer (score 3):

Simple enough, use a variable voltage regulator, like the typical LM117 or LM317 set to about 2.8V, with your 5V USB supply.  Assuming the LEDs already have a resistor(s), and all ten in parallel use 200mA, no need for a heat sink. You could probably do without the filter caps as well.